# Doubt regarding Continuous Random Variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I do know that the probability of random variables (say $X$ and $Y$) taking specific values is considered to be zero (i.e. $P(X=x,Y=y) = 0$). My doubt, however, is how do I determine the probability of events wherein ($a<X<b,Y=y$)(i.e. $P(a<X<b,Y=y)$.

I am aware that the probability of events such as ($a<X<b\mid Y=y$) can be evaluated by finding the conditional probability density function of $X$ and integrating the function over the interval $(a, b)$. But what about the case above? Is it also equal to zero? If so, could you please provide a detailed example to clarify the doubt? I have been struggling with continuous random variables for some time now.

Also, are the theorems valid for continuous random variables same/analogous to those of discrete random variables? A detailed explanation would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's a common confusion that beginners have. If $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables, then $P(a<X<b,Y=y)\leq P(Y=y)=0$ and hence $P(a<X<b,Y=y)=0$. But on the other hand $P(a<X<b|Y=y)$ is **NOT** a real number but rather a random variable by itself. That's why I rather prefer the notation $P(a<X<b|Y)$. For different values of $Y$, $P(a<X<b|Y)$ takes different values. Once you learn measure theory and then conditional expectation and then regular conditional probability, then things will be rigorously clear to you. Untill then, you have to work with intuition.

Comment: A downvote? Seriously? What is with the users of this site right now???? It is becomming a serious problem. Atleast be honest enough to state the reason for your downvote. If it is just about the edits, then it is better to leave a comment asking the op to edit and also link a mathjax tutorial alongwith. A direct downvote on a suffciently well written and posed question/doubt will only discourage users from at all participating in this site.

Comment: "Also, are the theorems valid for continuous random variables same/analogous to those of discrete random variables ?A detailed explanation would be much appreciated." Are you sure these are all the questions for today, Sir?

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation @ Mr.Gandalf Sauron. Also, is the theorem for conditional probability in case of discrete random variables valid for continuous random variables. I believe it should not be because the denominator would be zero in that case (i.e P(Y=y) is zero))

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron.  You say *"on the other hand $P(a<X<b \mid Y=y)$ is NOT a real number but rather a random variable by itself"* - I so not see this.  To the extent it is defined at all (you may need to take the limit with a small neighbourhood around $y$), I would have thought it could be seen as a function of $y$ and if $y$ is a given value then it *is* a real number

Comment: @Henry Well to define it completely rigorously, I need to talk about regular conditional probability.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron - my query was about "a random variable in itself".  That is the case for $P(a<X<b \mid Y)$, which is a function of the random variable $Y$, but I do not see it for $P(a<X<b \mid Y=y)$

Comment: @Henry Well it is a random variable. It is $E(\mathbf{1}_{a<X<b}|\sigma(Y))$. It is a conditional expectation which is a random variable by itself and is infact defined in a n almost sure sence. Now if $X$ and $Y$ happen to have a joint density, then we can claim that $E(\mathbf{1}_{a<X<b}|\sigma(Y))=\frac{\int_{a}^{b}\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x,y)\,dydx}{\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x,y)\,dx}$ and this equality should be viewed in an almost sure sense. And now$P(a<X<b|Y=y)$ is **defined** to be $\frac{\int_{a}^{b}\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x,y)\,dydx}{\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x,y)\,dx}$ which really is a random variable.

Comment: @Henry $P(a<X<b|Y=y)$ or $P(a<X<b|Y)$ are just notations which denote $\frac{\int_{a}^{b}\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x,y)\,dydx}{\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x,y)\,dx}$ in this case. Now obviously, the RHS in reality is only different when $y$ is different. But there may exist $\omega$ and $\omega'$ for which $Y(\omega)=Y(\omega')=y$. So even though it seems that it is rather a real function depending on $y$ (which it is I agree) but the domain of this "function" is the probability space $(\Omega,\sigma(Y),P)$ and not $\Bbb{R}$. So it is in every sense a random variable.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron I do not see $P(a<X<b\mid Y=y)$ and $P(a<X<b \mid Y)$ as the same thing.  I would say the first is $f(y)$ where $y$ is a value and the second $f(Y)$ where $Y$ is a random variable.

Comment: @Henry I see no point in doing the distinction even if strightly speaking you are right. If you have a more precise assumption on $Y$ (it belongs to a set for example), then it should be written explicitely. But if not, it is common practice to view these two terms as equal and to stick with the one that is the more convenient to you depending on the context.

Comment: @Henry Both are just notations and both equal(**almost surely**) the expression $\frac{\int_{a}^{b}\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x,y)dydx}{\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x,Y(\omega))dx}$. You are claiming that $P(a<X<b|Y=y)$ is $f(y)$ but it should be $f(Y(\omega))$. Now obviously a composition of two functions $f(g(x))$ can be written as $f(y)$ where $y=g(x)$ and really does depend only on y, i.e. different values for different $y$. But $f\circ g$ is a function of $x$. Here, our $x$ is just $\omega$ from the probability space $(\Omega,\sigma(Y),P)$.

Comment: @Henry One can view this as either equal to $E(\mathbf{1}_{a<X<b}|\sigma(Y))$ in which case it should be thought of as a random variable. Otherwise, it can be thought of as a regular conditional probability $\nu(\cdot, X^{-1}(a,b))=\frac{\int_{a}^{b}\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x,y)\,dydx}{\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x,\cdot)\,dx}$ in which case this is treated as a real function of $y$.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment.

I would recommend to read Mr Gandalf Sauron's comment again word for word. In particular the sentence containing **NOT**. The formulas that reconcile both notions of conditional expectation are

\begin{align}\underbrace{E[X|Y=y]}_{\color{red}{\text{function of $y$}}}&=a\underbrace{\frac{P(X=a,Y=y)}{P(Y=y)}}_{\color{red}{\text{number}}}
+b\underbrace{\frac{P(X=b,Y=y)}{P(Y=y)}}_{\color{red}{\text{number}}}\,,\tag{1}\\[4mm]
\underbrace{E[X|Y]}_{\color{red}{\text{random variable }}}&=a\frac{P(X=a,Y=y)}{P(Y=y)}\underbrace{1_{\{y\}}(Y)}_{\color{red}{\text{r.v.}}}
+b\frac{P(X=b,Y=y)}{P(Y=y)}\underbrace{1_{\{y\}}(Y)}_{\color{red}{\text{r.v.}}}\\[4mm]
&+a\frac{P(X=a,Y=z)}{P(Y=z)}\underbrace{1_{\{z\}}(Y)}_{\color{red}{\text{r.v.}}}
+b\frac{P(X=b,Y=z)}{P(Y=z)}\underbrace{1_{\{z\}}(Y)}_{\color{red}{\text{r.v.}}}\tag{2}
\end{align}
where I assume for simplicity that $X,Y$ are random variables that take only the values $a,b$ respectively $y,z\,.$
Plug in $y$ for $Y$ into (2) and you get (1). We write the number
$$
\frac{P(X=b,Y=z)}{P(Y=z)}=P(X=b\,|Y\,=y)\tag{3}
$$
which is the conditional expectation we learned in elementary probability.

- Using the bar $|$ in several contexts (1), (2), (3) leads to a lot of confusion. (Your question could be another example of that.)

When $Y$ is a continuous r.v. then $P(Y=y)=0$ and the right hand sides of (1) and (2) break down.
The left hand sides are still well defined (but differently). You should study this in the standard literature or take classes and not ask MSE to start from scratch reproducing the entire literature about discrete and continuous random variables.

Comment: Very clear explanation Kurt(+1). I remember the days when I used to get confused by conditional probability during my undergrad. It was only after a measure theoratic course in probability that things started to make sense.